# Does this sound natural to you ? - "I am really confident in English"

Tags: word-choice, grammar

Does this sound natural ?

A: Are you good at English ?

K: Sure ! **I'm really really confident in English.**

Comment: *with* sounds better than *in*, imo.

Comment: Nothing wrong with saying it. It's awfully formal, but maybe that's what A: really wants to know, so K: is demonstrating it. A more confident answer (like K: _Sure._) would not **mention** being confident, but rather would demonstrate it. For instance, which statement inspires more confidence in the addressee: _I'm confident the brake is off_ versus _The brake is off_?

Comment: @Araucaria ; Would using _with_ stress that _K_ has a good _command_ of the language. Is this how it would sound different from _in_?

Comment: @Itsme I'm not sure! JohnLawler's comment above is spot on though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not wrong, but it's not necessarily a natural idiom that a native speaker would use.  You might say "*I'm proficient in English,* which is a bit more formal, or *I'm great at English,* which is more informal, but *sounds* more confident.  If you wanted to use the actual word *confident*, you'd need something like *I'm confident in my English skills* --which actually doesn't sound that confident at all.

Your phrase, as it stands, technically means that you are confident when you speak English, but not necessarily because you speak English well.

Comment: Heaven knows being confident in your English and being competent in English are two different things.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is more common to say "I'm really really confident in *my* English."

Consider this: if you say that you are confident in English, and if I hear this statement without any context, I might think that you have faith in the English language rather in your ability to speak it.

Answer (score 1):

No, it doesn't sound natural. Usually one would respond with the same terms as being asked.

The asking party is asking about the ability:

> Are you good at *thing*?

The proper response is, if true:

> Yes, I am [very or really] good at *thing*.

If false:

> No, I am not [very or really] good at *thing*.

More information on really vs very:
[ELU](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/76784/the-difference-between-really-and-very), [Learner's Dictionary](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/qa/pretty-fairly-really-very-and-quite). And if you're really interested in a long treatise on *really*, [Between epistemic modality and degree: the case of really (pdf)](http://lup.lub.lu.se/luur/download?func=downloadFile&recordOId=527128&fileOId=1590141) by Carita Paradis